# iOS Passing Preprocessor Macros from main project to embedded framework

Tags: ios, xcode, c-preprocessor, ios-frameworks

I am currently creating framework and separating part of my codes to framework. In my code, I have like this.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define SERVER_PREFIX @"http://example1.com/"

#elif STAGING
#define SERVER_PREFIX @"http://example2.com/"

#elif RELEASE
#define SERVER_PREFIX @"http://example3.com/"
#endif
```

[image]

I need to separate those into framework. If main project switch between those, I want my framework to automatically change also. I am not sure whether it is a good approach and can be done or not. How shall I do?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't approach the problem with pre processor macros, you should make the framework configurable so you actually pass it the required value at runtime. This is what actually makes the framework reusable...

Comment: What if you wanted to restrict some features in the case that the source is being built only with the Debug configuration, e.g. if there was something you wanted to allow a developer with the source code to do/bypass vs. something you wanted to impose on a built, no source code, Release version. That's my issue.

Comment: Sure @VincilBishop you can do that with preprocessor macros